# Обьедененные скрипты js

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте, было 2 скрипта. Первый добавляет $post['id'] (номер сообщения) в форму по клику. А второй скрипт открывает окно, которое скрыто. Хотел сделать что бы когда нажимаешь на "Ответ" - появлялась форма и в нее добавлялся $post['id'] (номер сообщения). Я объединил эти 2 скрипта, модальное окно открывается, но $post['id'] (номер сообщения) в форму добавляться не хочет. Не скажете в чем дело?
http://jsfiddle.net/NDHuZ/

Comment: Для начала неплохо бы убрать `html`-теги с поля `javascript`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NDHuZ/2/  
Done. Если Вам легче будет определить проблему.

Comment: у меня Ваш пример криво отображает html окно, в нём дублируются ссылки и "усы" (}).

Comment: Не знаю, у меня все нормально отображается.  
Там, кстати, еще <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> подключить надо, и стиля кусок есть. Не знаю, может поможет:  

    #boxes .window {  
    position:fixed;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    width:700px;  
    height:300px;  
    display:none;  
    z-index:9999;  
    padding:20px;  
    }  
#boxes #dialog {  
    width:700px;   
    height:403px;  
    padding:10px;  
    }